# how to print specific list of items from a dict in python?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, dictionary

i am trying to print only the "s" & "t" values from the dictionary of app_locate using the input_list list of ['s' , 't'] but i get the whole list of app_locate instead.

```
user_input = 'st'

input_list = list(user_input)


app_locate = {
    's' : r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe',
    'd' : r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9036\Discord.exe',
    't' : r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe',
    'f' : r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe',
}
    
for input_list in app_locate:
    print(app_locate[input_list])
```

im not sure what im doing wrong here.

im rather new to python, sorry!

thank you for your help

Comment: You are iterating over the dictionary `app_locate`. You want to iterate over `input_list`. 

Modify the for loop to `for x in input_list` and use `x` to get the value from `app_locate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to convert user input to a list as you can just iterate over the string as follows:

```
user_input = 'st'

app_locate = {
    's' : r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe',
    'd' : r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9036\Discord.exe',
    't' : r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe',
    'f' : r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe',
}
    
for key in user_input:
    print(app_locate.get(key, f"Key {key} not found"))
```

Comment: thank you so much, i was getting so confused.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're iterating over the keys of the `app_locate` dictionary instead of iterating over the items in the `input_list`. You need to iterate over the `input_list` and check if each character is in the `app_locate` dictionary. Here's the corrected version of your code:

```py
user_input = 'st'

input_list = list(user_input)

app_locate = {
    's' : r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe',
    'd' : r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9036\Discord.exe',
    't' : r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe',
    'f' : r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe',
}
    
for char in input_list:
    if char in app_locate:
        print(app_locate[char])
```

This code will iterate over each character in `input_list` and check if it exists as a key in the `app_locate` dictionary. If it does, it will print the corresponding value. This way, only the values associated with 's' and 't' will be printed.

Comment: "If it does, it will print the corresponding value". What happens if it does not exist?

Comment: If the character from input_list does not exist as a key in the app_locate dictionary, nothing will be printed. This is because the if char in app_locate: statement only executes the indented block of code (print(app_locate[char])) if the character exists as a key in the dictionary.

If you want to handle the case where a character does not exist in the dictionary, you can add an else block to print a message or perform some other action.

Comment: That's not right. You will get a KeyError exception